# how to add to HttpResponseMessage file and string

Tags: c#, http, serialization

I have a code that return file with `HttpResponseMessage`, I want to add the contact also string, how can I do that?

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetPlaylistXml(int playlistId, [FromBody] JObject data)
{
    ....
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(playList));
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(memStream, playList);

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(memStream.ToArray(), 0, (int)memStream.Length)
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = playlist.Title + ".xml"
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        var response = ResponseMessage(result);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are trying to do.  Would you like to return the playlist xml along with other metadata?

Comment: yes, I want to add playlist xml and another string

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you're asking, but if what you want to do is to return multiple values from a function, I would suggest you create a class containing those values and return that.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options depending on your preference and possibly limitations based on the existing platform:

### Option 1

You can leave your code as is and read the file from the stream and read the file name from the headers (I'd personally recommend this unless there is some limitation preventing you from doing this)

### Option 2

Create a model and return both in json format:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetPlaylistXml(int playlistId, [FromBody] JObject data)
{
    ....
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(playList));
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(memStream, playList);

        var returnModel = new 
        {
           Title = playList.Title,
           // either a byte array (which is converted to Base64, or the XML string)
           Playlist = memStream.ToArray() 
        };

        return Json(returnModel);
    }
}
```

#### Option 3

Make your endpoints more REST like and have two endpoints, one for retrieving information about the playlist and one for retrieving the playlist file:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("playlist/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetPlaylistMetaData(int id)
{
    return Json(new {
        Id = 1,
        Title = "My Playlist",
        TrackCount = 24,
        ...
    });
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("playlist/{id}/file")]
public IHttpActionResult GetPlaylistFile(int id)
{
    ....
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(playList));
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(memStream, playList);

        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(memStream.ToArray(), 0, (int)memStream.Length)
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = playlist.Title + ".xml"
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        var response = ResponseMessage(result);

        return response;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.